# Forcing the preloader in captivate to show up

Tags: preloader, adobe-captivate

We have a captivate 6 project and am trying different pre-loaders. I want that even when we publish the project locally to test it, the preloader should show up for a few seconds, even though the presentation loads very fast. This is just to test the different pre-loaders. One option is to everytime.  upload the presentation on a slow server to test it, but was wondering if there is a trick to make that happen even while publishing it locally, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see:
http://captivate.adobe.com/captivate/topics/with_captivate_6_the_preloader_does_not_seem_to_function_when_i_set_the_to_50_my_preloader_disappears_athttp://captivate.adobe.com/captivate/topics/preloader_setting_in_captivate_6_doesnt_work

Did you try this fix:
http://www.cpguru.com/fix-for-the-adobe-captivate-6-javascript-bug